# docker pull hyperledger/fabric-peer is throwing error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pull

***docker pull hyperledger/fabric-peer*** is throwing error.

When I tried to [setup docker locally](https://blog.craftworkz.co/run-hyperledger-locally-with-docker-4f3bcb815c03) and "***docker-compose up***" not up and runnning.

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `docker pull hyperledger/fabric-peer` will only pull the image to your machine. Your local images can be listed with `docker images`. In order to use `docker-compose up`, you need to have the docker-compose.yml file in the working directory.

Comment: what is the error you are getting when the image is being pulled?

Comment: Error information- > "Error response from daemon: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest not found."

Comment: I am looking for "BLOCKCHAIN ON LOCAL SETUP
INSTRUCTIONS". Any help on this grateful.

Comment: Followed steps mentioned @ https://blog.craftworkz.co/run-hyperledger-locally-with-docker-4f3bcb815c03

Comment: same problem over here!

Comment: I have the same problen. This doesn't help:`docker pull hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest` and this `docker pull hyperledger/fabric-peer:v1.0.2`

Comment: use arch and version in image as: `hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.1` .

Answer (score 1):

You can go and grab the version that suits you from here: 
https://store.docker.com/community/images/hyperledger/fabric-peer/tags

After that run this command

```
docker pull hyperledger/fabric-peer:your_version
```

Answer (score 0):

[Hyperledger readthedocs](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/samples.html#binaries)

I had to download the platform specific binaries.

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap-1.0.1.sh | bash
```

This will pull a bunch of images, but it worked for me.